# Casselman-Shalika formula for split reductive groups

Tags: nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory

In the paper of Casselman and Shalika they give an explicit formula for the spherical Whittaker function of an unramified principal series.  Apparently, upon combining their formula with the Weyl character formula, one can get an evaluation of the Whittaker function in terms of the Satake parameter of the representation.  Can someone please explain how to do this, or give me a reference where it is done?

Comment: It's always helpful to add a reference to the paper itself, which is freely available at numdam.org:

 http://www.numdam.org/item?id=CM_1980__41_2_207_0

Though I can't point to a helpful further reference, I'd note that in the years since MathSciNet began tracking citations in standard journals, this one has been cited 84 times.  

Answer (score 2):

I think something very close to what is asked in the original question is explained by Haines, Kottwitz and A. Prasad in their [review article](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0309168).

Comment: This does seem to be a helpful reference (which I've corrected to get the link right).

Answer (score 1):

A partial reference is http://sporadic.stanford.edu/bump/rallis.ps.  This is a survey article but the discussion is perhaps complete enough to fill in the details for $GL_n$.  The general case of an arbitrary split reductive group is also discussed but less completely (there's surely a more comprehensive treatment of this somewhere in the literature, but I'm afraid I don't know where).  In either case you might want to supplement these with a discussion of the Satake isomorphism itself.  One reference I know for this is Section 2.3 of Gelbart/Shahidi's book *Analytic properties of automorphic $L$-functions*.